# Find the parametric equation for the line that is tangent to the given curve at the given parameter value.

Tags: calculus

Find the parametric equation for the line that is tangent to r(t) = (5t$^2$, 3t - 4, 3t$^3$) at t = t$_0$ = 1.

My solution is incorrect. Please specify exactly where and why it is incorrect, as well as the correct solution. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: your parametrization is also correct, see y(t+1). However it is standard to assume that y(0) would correspond to the given point

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the line is: $l(t) = r(1) + t\cdot r'(1)=(5,-1,3)+ t(10,3,9)= (10t+5, 3t-1, 9t+3)$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought the formula for a tangent line is f$'$(a) (x-a) + f(a)? So wouldn't we have (t-1) in this case?

Comment: Notice how answers in past threads have also used the tangent line equation y = f$'$(a) (x-a) + f(a): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315618/given-value-x-find-the-tangent-line-to-the-curve?rq=1